# 3 square in a circle (geometric question)

Tags: geometry

There is three square in a circle like the picture attached.
  How can find radius of circle  ?
I know that's not a hard problem,but I was away from geometry for years.  If possible give me hint or idea to start to solving.   Thanks in advance.
[image]

the smallest side is $6$
and medium square side is $6+6$
and big side is $6+6+6$
But I got stuck here and not to go over there ...

Comment: Draw the radius from the centre of the circle to either of the vertices of the big square touching the circle. Then apply Pythagoras.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri: where is the centre according to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Equations:
$$ a + b = 36 $$
$$ a^2 + 9^2 = r^2 $$
$$ b^2 + 3^2 = r^2 $$

Using 2 and 3:
$$ b^2 - a^2 = 72 $$
Factoring:
$$ (b-a)(b+a) = 72 $$
$$ (b-a)36 = 72 $$
$$ b-a = 2 $$
Adding the first:
$$ 2b = 38 $$
$$ b = 19 $$
$$ a = 17 $$
Adding 2 eq y 3 eq:
$$ 19^2 + 17^2 +9^2 + 3^2 = 2r^2 $$
$$ 370 = r^2 $$
$$ r = \sqrt{370} = 19.23.... $$

Answer (score 9):

It is only the Pythagorean theorem:
[image]

Comment: I am in doubt that you see the picture!  please look again,it is not a symmetric sahpe.

Comment: @Khosrotash, it is a symmetric shape Sir.

Comment: @Khosrotash, You can move the middle square to the center as you wish. Notice that the other two squares  are touching the circle and it is indeed a symmetric shape.

Comment: I got that point now... it is clear now. thank you

Comment: @Khosrotash, khaahesh mikonam.

Comment: mer30 hhamvatan

Comment: @Khosrotash, I fixed the diagram , is it better now?

Comment: What theorem allows you to state “$(6+12+18)\times X = 6\times12$”?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, it is called Intersecting Chord Theorem. You can read about it here: https://www.mathopenref.com/chordsintersecting.html

Comment: (+1) Nice use of the [Power of a Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)

Answer (score 2):

Coordinate Geometry works.

Draw the horizontal diameter of the circle.
Let the center of the line segment between the squares be the origin $(0,0)$.
Let the center of the circle be $ (x, 0 )$.

---

> What is the coordinate of the top right blue point?

$ $

> What is the coordinate of the top left blue point?

$ $

> Hence, what is an equation that we can write?

$ $

> Hence, what is the radius of the circle?

Comment: By the way I just saw your appearance on Numberphile. Cool stuff!

Comment: Thanks! $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Apply the Pythagorean theorem to the triangles ADO and CBO to match the overall length AB = 36,

$$\sqrt{r^2-9^2} + \sqrt{r^2-3^2} =36$$

Solve to obtain the radius $r=\sqrt{370}$.

Answer (score 2):

The [circumradius of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3610959) is
$$
R=\frac{abc}{4A}
$$
where $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle and $A$ is its area.

[image]

The sides are $18$, $\sqrt{36^2+6^2}=6\sqrt{37}$, and $\sqrt{36^2+12^2}=12\sqrt{10}$ and the area is $\frac12\,18\cdot36=324$. Therefore, the circumradius is
$$
R=\frac{18\cdot6\sqrt{37}\cdot12\sqrt{10}}{4\cdot324}=\sqrt{370}
$$

Comment: :+1 nice ,very nice idea