# To find the radius of this circle.

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm no math wizard, and this question however has been bothering me a lot. In my opinion, adequate information isn't present. But I need an expert opinion.

[image: we've to find the radius of this circle]

The boxes are all squares.

Comment: It is doable. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615450/65203

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596144/3-square-in-a-circle-geomet

Comment: @YvesDaoust And likely the source of that problem is also the same.

Comment: thanks, it did solve the problem, thanks everyone.